# Setting a max amount of input for a rich text box but allow other special keys

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to check and see if a rich text box is over 4000 characters and if so then don't add to the RTF. However the problem I have come accross is that I can't seem to find an option for "allow special characters" kinda deal. I allowed backspace and delete but then theres ctrl commands, shift, etc.

```
private void RichEditControl_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var tr = new TextRange(richEditControl.Document.ContentStart, richEditControl.Document.ContentEnd);

    e.Handled = (tr.Text.Length >= 4000 && !(e.Key == Key.Back || e.Key == Key.Delete));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void RichEditControl_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var tr = new TextRange(richEditControl.Document.ContentStart, richEditControl.Document.ContentEnd);

    e.Handled = tr.Text.Length - richEditControl.Selection.Text.Length>= 4000;
}
```